# An error in the timer function (MATLAB R2014a)

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I am stuck in an error of timer function. Although I have tried to search, I find no answer.

```
function figure1_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles) 
global t
t = timer( 'ExecutionMode', 'fixedRate', 'StartDelay',1, 'Period',1,'TasksToExecute',150); 
t.TimerFcn = {@my_callback_fcn};
```

The error I got is:

> Error while evaluating TimerFcn for timer 'timer-1'
>   Too many input arguments.

My MATLAB version is R2014a. The `start` function is called `pushbutton2_Callback` function.
I have tried to change `Period` to `1.0`, `TasksToExecute` to `inf` or `TimerFcn` in the call to `timer`. It does not help.

Is there anyone who can help me out?

Comment: the first line of `my_callback_fcn` (the prototype asked by Matt above) should have at least 2 input variables (the handle of the calling object and the event data), even if you do not use them. So it should look like: `function my_callback_fcn(hobj,evt)`, or if you really do not use these variables, you can tell Matlab to ignore them `function my_callback_fcn(~,~)`

Comment: @Hoki Hello! My callback function is function *my_callback_fcn(handles,~)*. The error becomes **The name 'edit1' is not an accessible property for an instance of class 'timer objects'.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused because your provided callback function `my_callback_fcn` does not have two input arguments. You have *two possibilities* to solve that. Only do *one* of them:

1. Create an anonymous function with two input arguments when you assign the timer callback:

   ```
   t.TimerFcn = {@(obj,event)my_callback_fcn};
   ```
2. Add two input arguments to `my_callback_fcn` so your first line of that function looks like:

   ```
   function my_callback_fcn(obj,event)
   ```

You can ignore the arguments with `~` if you do not need them in the function. So your code from the question could look like this:

```
t = timer('ExecutionMode', 'fixedRate', 'StartDelay',1, 'Period',1, 'TasksToExecute',150); 
t.TimerFcn = {@(~,~)my_callback_fcn};
```

[Here](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/timer-callback-functions.html) is some more information on timer callback functions.

---

*To address [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38671847/an-error-in-the-timer-function-matlab-r2014a/38672039?noredirect=1#comment64724507_38672039) comment and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38671847/an-error-in-the-timer-function-matlab-r2014a/38672039?noredirect=1#comment64724563_38671847) one:*

Don't attempt to apply both solutions at the same time because then you'll add two arguments to the function prototype and then don't provide it. The result would be the following error:

> Error while evaluating TimerFcn for timer 'timer-1'
>   Not enough input arguments.

You only need to do solution 2 according to the prototype you posted in your comment. Here is a working demo:

```
function timertest
t = timer('ExecutionMode', 'fixedRate', 'StartDelay',1, 'Period',1, 'TasksToExecute',150); 
t.TimerFcn = {@my_callback_fcn};
start(t); pause on; pause; stop(t); delete(t);

function my_callback_fcn(handles,~)
handles;
disp('xy');
```

Comment: Hello ~ Thanks for your help!  I try <t.TimerFcn = {@(~,~)my_callback_fcn};> and the error information is *Not enough input arguments.* And I try what Hoki said the error information becomes * The name 'edit1' is not an accessible property for an instance of class 'timer objects'.* It is so weird because edit1 has no business with the time object

Comment: I am sorry that I don't know how to input code in the comment

Comment: @standerQiu Have you applied the two possibilities at the same time? This won't work because then you try to call the function without any arguments (solution 1) when it requires two (the ones you would have added by doing solution 2). To format code in comments, enclose it with a back-tick. [Here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/24794/298845) is more information on that.

Comment: My last comment is the result of applying both solutions. I have deleted it

Comment: Sorry for replying late. The latest solution you give could not solve my question: *The name 'edit1' is not an accessible property for an instance of class 'timer objects'.* That is exactly the first comment

Comment: @standerQiu The error containing *edit1* is not related to the question asked here and is most likely caused because you have `t.edit1` somewhere in the code. You could ask a new question giving all the details to the problem with *edit1* including the code where the error occurs.

Comment: Acutally there is no `t.edit` . *edit1* has no business with the *t* ..

Comment: @standerQiu Without seeing the code that produces this error, it is impossible to help you solve the issue. The error says that you are trying to access the property `edit1` of a timer-object. Be it named `t` or differently... I suggest [asking a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) for getting this error solved. Please post *all* the relevant code for it and be specific. The best is to post a [mcve].